# Admin : Select category -> show subcategory using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

how to show category and subcategory :
 Admin : Select category -> show subcategory   using Django

```
class Category(models.Model):
    categoryName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.categoryName

class Subcategory(models.Model):
    subcategoryName=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subcategoryName


class Product(models.Model):
    productName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    productImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.productName
```

[admin product form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YenEN.png)

Comment: You're looking for this https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking is a reverse relationship, to do that you use  models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE). 
The official doc is here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

I hope it helps
Best

Answer (score 1):

remove `Subcategory` model and write `Category` model like this

```
class Category(models.Model):
    categoryName=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("Category", null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.categoryName
```

and remove `subcategory` field from `Product`.
Writing like this is more neat

Comment: getting error     parent = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True)
NameError: name 'Category' is not defined

Comment: use this : " "
`parent = models.ForeignKey("Category", null=True, blank=True)`